# facebook graph api app permission Workplace Account

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-workplace

I have been developing using the FB.api(), but now I get the following error message

`"This app does not have permission to manage this Workplace account"`

when I try and make a new post, but I can still delete posts!!

I do not think I have changed any permissions, The Page is a Test Page, My Account is set up as administrator for both The Page and The App.  I cannot see anywhere on either The Page or The App where I can provide permissions.

I have not got a Workplace Account, and cannot see how I might add/edit/remove one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, how bizzar....If you post a new message with FB.api() and have property

`formatting: 'MARKDOWN'`

then you get an error about permission on Workplace Account!!